# Terraform: Inspect module variables and outputs

Tags: terraform

One of my modules - let it be `a` - has an output definition as

```
output "data_table_arn" {
  value = aws_dynamodb_table.data_table.*.arn
}
```

This is accessed one level above in module `b`

```
module "b" {
  source                      = "../c"
  data_lookup_table_arn       = module.a.data_table_arn
```

The code above makes the variable `module.a.data_table_arn` accessible to module `c` through the variable `data_lookup_table_arn`. And now I am trying to access it in module `c` in an aws policy document definition

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dynamo-read-policy-document" {
  count = local.one_if_uses_dynamo

  statement {
    actions = ["dynamodb:GetItem"]
    resources = [
      var.data_table_arn
    ]
  }
}
```

The exception I am getting is

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.
```

I want to debug this thing somehow and I cannot find a way to inspect the outputs or the variables defined inside a module. I can list the resources using `terraform state list <resource_name>` but this is not what I really want to do here.

1. How can I inspect the variables and outputs of a TF module?
2. Is this even possible?
3. Can you see anything faulty with my approach
4. I though of also using a heredoc instead of a `aws_iam_policy_document` but I would still need to make use of the output mentioned above - but this time in an interpolation I guess. Is this better or worse? They should be the same thing right?

Comment: Have you tried `terraform state show module.a.aws_dynamodb_table.data_table`?

Comment: That implies the resource has not yet applied with a CREATE operation. Is that correct?

Comment: `terraform state show module.a.aws_dynamodb_table.data_table` I don't know how useful the output of this command is. This does not guarantee that the outputs are working as they supposed to or that the variables on `b` or `c` are populated the way they are supposed to from the outputs of `a`

Comment: the output is 
```
No instance found for the given address!

This command requires that the address references one specific instance.
To view the available instances, use "terraform state list". Please modify 
the address to reference a specific instance.
```